# SimpleSSHD Missing SCP?

Tags: ssh, oneplus

I successfully got SimpleSSHD running on my OnePlus 7T and I can SSH into the phone fine and I can also connect using WinSCP.  However, whenever I try to transfer a file, I get an error 127, which apparently means the scp command wasn't found.  I can confirm from the CLI that it thinks scp doesn't exist.  But does that not come with SimpleSSHD?  Am I missing something with the installation?  I should add, I am transferring files to /sdcard/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with the app author, it sounds like it's an issue that may not get resolved, but he confirmed that he had to do some funny stuff to get scp working and the Android updates have probably broken it.  So I ended up using Termux instead and wrote some documentation on it, in case anyone comes across this later.

## Termux Android SSH Server Setup

### SSH Setup

1. Download and install [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&gl=US) on the phone
2. Enable File Storage permissions for the app (I had to manually do this)
3. Start the app and run these next steps in the app
4. Install dropbear and openssh

   ```
   pkg upgrade
   pkg install openssh
   # When OpenSSH asks about overwriting your local config file, answer N to keep the local file
   ```
5. Run the command `passwd` to generate a login pasword
6. Start the SSH server

   ```
   sshd
   ```

   - NOTE To Stop the SSH server, run this `pkill sshd`

Ref: https://www.crisisshelter.org/install-ssh-in-termux-openssh/

### Key-based Auth Setup (Windows)

#### Generate Keys

1. Download https://www.puttygen.com/
2. Run puttygen
3. Select:

   1. RSA
   2. Bits: (2048 or 4096 for better encryption)
4. Click Generate
5. Wiggle mouse in blank space of program
6. Copy the public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file and save it to a file named `authorized_keys`

   - NOTE: Output should look like this

     `ssh-rsa 1231AD_REALLY_LONG_KEY_HERE_FG123= rsa-key-20220806`
7. Save the private key as `id_rsa.ppk`

#### Send Public Key to Phone

1. Connect to the phone's IP using WinSCP on port `8022`
2. Enter a blank username and then the password set above
3. Manually change to `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` (Note, the location of the home directory may be different so use what your path shows)
4. Transfer the `authorized_keys` file created above to this folder

#### Setup Key in Kitty/Putty

1. Setup the SSH connection as usual, being sure to use port `8022` and the phone IP
2. Go to `Connection->SSH->Auth` and select the `id_rsa.ppk` file saved from puttygen
3. Be sure to go back to `Session` to name and save the connection
4. Click `Open` to connect
5. Hit `enter` to skip the username and it will use the certificate to authenticate

#### Setup Key in WinSCP

1. Setup a `New Site` using the option at the top of the connection list
2. Select `SCP` as the file protocol
3. Enter the phone IP and port `8022`
4. Click `Advanced` and navigate to `SSH->Authentication`
5. Select the `id_rsa.ppk` generated from puttygen and click `OK`
6. Click `Save` and name the connection
7. Click `Login`
8. Click `OK` to bypass the username prompt and it will use the certificate to authenticate

### Disable Password Authentication

1. After ensuring you can login using the certificate, log back into the phone using SSH
2. Edit the sshd config file

   ```
   nano $PREFIX/etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```
3. Modify the following line to this setting:

   ```
   PasswordAuthentication no
   ```
4. Save changes and exit with `CTRL+X`
5. For good measure, set the password to some random password

   ```
   passwd
   # Enter some RANDOM_STRING
   ```
6. You can exit the shell session now

### Termux Logs

SSH daemon does logging to Android system log, you can view it by running `logcat -s 'sshd:*'`. You can do that either from Termux or ADB.

Ref: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access